# Zipping together Lists within a Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, subprocess

I have a Dictionary that looks like:

```
hyperparams = {
    'epochs': [30, 50],
    'learning_rate': [0.0001, 0.0001],
    'train_batch_size': [36, 36],
    'dev_batch_size': [36, 36],
    'test_batch_size': [36, 36],
    'dropout_rate': [.05, .4],
    'dropout_rate2': [-1, -1],
    'dropout_rate3': [-1, -1],
    'dropout_rate4': [0, 0],
    'dropout_rate5': [0, 0],
    'dropout_rate6': [-1, -1]
}
```

I would like to zip together all of the lists and then iterate through them. Is there an elegant and efficient way to do this? Maybe somehow unpacking the value.

My end goal is to take all of the first elements of each list (e.g. [0], pass them to a subprocess call, then for the next set of elements of each list [1] pass that to a subprocess call, and so on.

Comment: ``zip(hyperparams.values())``  or ``zip(*hyperparams.values())`` ?

Comment: It seems that I always find the solution after typing up my Stackoverflow question. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are absolutely sure that values in your dictionary are all lists; you could do something like this to iterate through them all:

```
for key, value in hyperparams.items():
    for i in value:
        print(i) # or any other process that you'd wish
```